# How to pass ArrayList to JPA repository method from lambda expression?

Tags: java, java-stream

There is entity class:

```
public class Call {
    private String uniqId;
    private String gwNumber;
}

String line = "qwe-123,10\nrty-345,15\nasd-567,17";

Arrays.stream(result.split("\n")) // "\n" is used to separate data for each entity
    .forEach(
              s-> {
                    String[] callFields =  s.split(",");  // "," is used to separate data for each filed  of entity
                    Call call = new Call();
                    call.setUniqId(callFields[0]);
                    call.setGwNum(callFields[1]);
                    List<Call> callList = new ArrayList<>();
                    callList.add(call);
                   }
            );
```

How to pass callList to JPA repository.saveAll(callList) method ?

Comment: rather then declaring callingList inside declare it before your stream and then add all the values to it. Then call your save function from dao and pass list to it as argument. If your repo extends JPA or CRUD repo then they already have save function in them which takes list as an argument

Comment: first initial `callList` then pass it through `saveAll`. `Arrays.stream(line.split("\n")) 
                .map(s->s.split(",")).map(arr->new Call(arr[0],arr[1])) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should forget to call smth. from `Steram`. I do not say this is impossible, but it's not recommended.

```
class Call {}

List<Call> callList = Arrays.stream(result.split("\n"))
          .map(s -> {
             Call call = new Call();
             // ...
             return call;
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`List<Call> callList` could be written into DB.